# R data.table calculation conditioned upon multiple rows in other columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have data looking similar to this:

```
   Sample.Name Marker Height Size
1:    Sample01      A    450  100
2:    Sample01      A    420  120
3:    Sample01      B    700  140
4:    Sample01      C    750  160
5:    Sample01      D    300  180
6:    Sample01      D    340  200
```

which can be reproduced using the following code:

```
# Some example data.
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Sample.Name=rep("Sample01", 6),
             Marker=c("A","A","B","C","D","D"),
             Height=c(450,420,700,750,300,340),
             Size=c(seq(from=100, to=200,length.out = 6)))
```

There are one or two rows for each marker with **Height** and **Size** (can be NA). In reality there are also additional columns with allele values and other information not needed for the example. The data is not necessarily sorted by **Size**.

I want to calculate the ratio (Hb) between the heights of peaks for each marker (NA if there are only one peak). Hb can be calculated in several ways:

1) the smaller (i.e. lower) peak height divided by the larger (i.e. taller) peak height

2) the peak height of the shorter fragment divided by the peak height of the longer fragment

3) the opposite of 2) but that can be solved with the same strategy as 2) so we don't need to consider it here.

I am writing a function that should be able to perform all three calculations, using data.table. So far I have written the code to calculate 1) using a two-step approach:

```
# Identify the smaller and larger peak height and count number of peaks.
DT2 <- DT[, list(Small=min(Height), Large=max(Height), Peaks=.N),
      by=list(Sample.Name, Marker)]

# Divide only where there are two observed peaks.
DT2[Peaks==2, Hb:=Small/Large, by=list(Sample.Name, Marker)]
```

This generates the desired output:

```
>DT2
   Sample.Name Marker Small Large Peaks        Hb
1:    Sample01      A   420   450     2 0.9333333
2:    Sample01      B   700   700     1        NA
3:    Sample01      C   750   750     1        NA
4:    Sample01      D   300   340     2 0.8823529
```

However, I am stuck at how to calculate 2). I would have to look in **Size** to determine which of the two Height values to assign to 'Short' and 'Long' respectively. I have consulted the data.table help pages and search stackoverflow. Being far from an expert on data.table syntax I have been unable to find/recognise a solution for this specific problem. The desired output for 2) is identical to that for 1) with the exception of the first row where **Hb** would be 450/420=1.071429

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second calculation, you can do something like:

```
DT[, .(Hb = ifelse(.N == 2, Height[Size == min(Size)]/Height[Size == max(Size)], NA_real_))
   , .(Sample.Name, Marker)]     # where you pick up the Height at the smaller size divided 
                                 # by the Height at the larger size. Note that you have to 
                                 # explicitly specify the NA type to be real here since data.table
                                 # requires column type to be consistent

#    Sample.Name Marker        Hb
# 1:    Sample01      A 1.0714286
# 2:    Sample01      B        NA
# 3:    Sample01      C        NA
# 4:    Sample01      D 0.8823529
```

Comment: This solution works great! Also, I learnt how to calculate in one go using `ifelse`. Thanks!